# Making a dictionary for my calculated value

Tags: python

I have a txt file contain a list of 2 phone numbers and the duration between the two like this:

```
3058 1234 2:28
1650 00777666555 2:03
3928 00423775651 4:54
2222 3333 5:20
3058 00876543210 1:49
3058 1234 1:15
1650 00876543210 2:10
2222 1234 2:32
3928 00172839456 1:38
1111 00969633330 3:01
```

I have written a function to split the number and time and calculating them for the price:

```
def getSec(time):
    #change minute to second
    min, sec = time.split(':')
    return int(min) * 60 + int(sec)

def calPrice():
    f = open('calls.txt', 'r')
    print(f.read() + '\n')

    with open('calls.txt') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            anotherLineVar = line.split(' ')
            firstNumb = anotherLineVar[0]
           # print(firstNumb)
            secNumb = anotherLineVar[1]
            #print(secNumb)
            time = anotherLineVar[2]
            #print(time)
            if int(secNumb[0]) == 0:
                second = getSec(time)
                price = second * 1.50

calPrice()
```

So now the final step is in case if any call contain any second number starts with `00`, I will need to charge the calling number some fee. And I'll need add the charged number and the price in a list. For example the call of `1650 00777666555 2:03` and `3928 00423775651 4:54` will be charged a price is `184.5` and `441.0` so the dictionary will show as:

```
{1650:148.5
 3928:441.0}
```

I was try to do something like

```
#outside the if statement
dict = {}
#inside the if statement
dict[secNumb] = price
print(dict)
```

but the output is a mess:

```
{'00777666555': 184.5}
{'00777666555': 184.5, '00423775651': 441.0}
{'00777666555': 184.5, '00423775651': 441.0, '00876543210': 163.5}
{'00777666555': 184.5, '00423775651': 441.0, '00876543210': 195.0}
{'00777666555': 184.5, '00423775651': 441.0, '00876543210': 195.0, '00172839456': 147.0}
{'00777666555': 184.5, '00423775651': 441.0, '00876543210': 195.0, '00172839456': 147.0, '00969633330': 271.5}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In dict, if you want the keys to be numbers you have to convert them to numbers from string. Since you want the first number as key in the dict, assign it as the key while pushing it in the dict.

try this...

```
def getSec(time):
    #change minute to second
    min, sec = time.split(':')
    return int(min) * 60 + int(sec)

def calPrice():
    f = open('calls.txt', 'r')
    print(f.read() + '\n')
    dict = {}
    with open('calls.txt') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()    
        for line in lines:
            anotherLineVar = line.split(' ')
            firstNumb = anotherLineVar[0]
            secNumb = anotherLineVar[1]
            time = anotherLineVar[2]
            if int(secNumb[0]) == 0:
                second = getSec(time)
                price = second * 1.50
                dict[int(firstNumb)] = price
calPrice()
```

Answer (score 2):

looks like you want to use as key for your dict `firstNumb` variable:

```
my_dict = {}
my_dict[int(firstNumb)] = price
```